# Moving Wordpress pages from subdirectory to root

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url

Beginner mistake, but I've created all my new pages for my Wordpress site in a subdirectory to my original site, and now I wish to move all the pages I've made to my root directory in order to sort the URL to my website.

At the moment my new pages are stood in

```
www.mysite.com/wordpress-4.6.1/wordpress/
```

when I enter my site via browser. I've looked around here for advice and tried all that I can find, but nothing seems to solve my problem for some reason. I've tried to change the URL explicitly under the Wordpress general settings but that just crashed my website somehow, so I had to redefine WP_HOME and WP_SITEURL in wp-config.php in order to get it up and running again. I've since tried downloading .htaccess and index.php and changing a few lines in index.php and then placing them in the database root.

The problem I'm left with now is that when I set the URL explicitly in wp-config.php I can't change it under 'General Settings' in Wordpress anymore, and if I state the URL that I want explicitly in wp-config.php the site stops working.

What would you guys suspect is the culprit here? Why is it that I can't change the URL explicitly and get it to work, are there some database-stuff that's still pointing at my wordpress folders or do you think it's something else?

Sorry for the wall of text, but couldn't seem to formulate it any shorter. Immensely thankful for any help!

Comment: This is covered in the Wordpress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Thankyou for the tip! The instruction on that link did not work out for me though. But I managed to work it out by, in the code, remove the subfolders from WP_HOME URL and leave them on WP_SITEURL!

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the Wordpress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Comment: Thankyou for the tip! The instruction on that link did not work out for me though. But I managed to work it out by, in the code, remove the subfolders from WP_HOME URL and leave them on WP_SITEURL!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the URL on option table of database.

Comment: Thankyou fot the advice! The URL on option table of database was already changed though. But I managed to work it out by, in the code, remove the subfolders from WP_HOME URL and leave them on WP_SITEURL!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work it out! Since I couldn’t edit the Wordpress URL and Site URL directly in Wordpress I had to add this code to wp-config:

define('WP_HOME','http://mydomain.se/wordpress-4.6.1/wordpress');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://mydomain.se/wordpress-4.6.1/wordpress');

I assumed that I had to remove the /wordpress-4.6.1/wordpress from the WP_SITEURL since the “Site Address (URL)” is what I would have changed in Wordpress if it had been possible. Since that didn’t work I removed the subfolders from WP_HOME URL instead and left them on WP_SITEURL and that solved the problem!